# Outlook Quick Access Toolbar Search: Set default to "All Outlook Items"

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search, office365

Hi I am using Office through Office 365.

I want the default search location for the search bar in the Quick Access Toolbar to be "All Outlook items". I.e. equivalent to manually selecting it in the dropdown:

[image]

In settings I have set search to include results from all mailboxes, but it doesn't have any effect on the search bar in the Quick Access Toolbar.

[image]

But the default still looks like this. As you can see it is searching in "Current Mailbox".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/995106c4-1f4e-44ca-a432-3559f98ed95a/outlook-2016-instant-search-how-to-set-it-to-search-all-outlook-items-by-default?forum=officeitpro

Is this the same issue as you? If so, I am afraid it is not supported to set All Outlook Items as the default search scope.

Comment: :( It is the same issue... Thank you for letting me know

Comment: Here the same issue with my clients and as an IT it's hard to explain that such a simple option in the settings does not exists, almost but not